# Javascript error when trying to output a video

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a website, where a user can save a video to his library. My videos have ID's: 1,2,3 etc... But I'm getting this error and I don't know what is the problem.

That is the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not
>   defined     at HTMLLIElement.onclick (index.php:51)

Here is my JS code:

```
//Videos          
function show(vidIDs) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '././video_display.php', //the script to call to get data          
        data: 'vidIDs=' + vidIDs,
        dataType: 'json', //data format 
        success: function () {
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i < vidIDs.length; i++) {
                var video = document.createElement("VIDEO");
                video.src = vidIDs[i] + ".mp4";
                video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
                document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(video);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And my HTML code:

```
    <li data-toggle="modal" onclick='show(<?php include 'video_display.php'; ?>)' 
data-target="#video"><span class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></span>
```

The result should be that a pop-up appears displaying the videos.

Comment: Is it possible that your `li` is placed in an iFrame?

Comment: No, it is not. 'li' is part of the nav bar. A good assumption though.

Comment: What's the output of that php-include you want to pass as a parameter to show?

Comment: Is it nested inside another function, like `$(document).ready()`? Names referenced in `onclick` have to be in the global scope.

Comment: My problem here is that is is not enclosed in quotation marks, so if the output does not contain these on its own, you will receive a syntax error sooner or later anyway

Comment: My outputs are: "02", "01", etc.